# How to read notification and not show in status bar when application is closed or killed?

Tags: android, notifications, notification-listener

I am creating a demo for android and for that, I want to not show notifications for a specific application like WhatsApp, Facebook, Instagram, etc. And for that, I have added notificationlistner and it worked for me when the application is in the foreground or in the background but not in a killed state. And I want to make it happen in the application killed state.
It would be great if I get help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simpler answer for you-  just don't have those apps on the phone you're using to demo.  If necessary, buy a cheap used phone for your demo. Far less time and effort than trying hacks to make notifications of other apps disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But I want to make a demo that blocks other application's notifications.

Comment: @MayankBalar If you find a way, Google will close it down as soon as they know about it.  They don't want apps to be able to hide each other's notifications, that's far more likely to be malicious than useful behavior.  So best of luck, but its not going to happen.